# How to scrape data from website when the request returns error

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping

For the past days I've been trying different ways to extract the exchange rate for the USD from `https://www.fibank.bg/en/currency-rates` using JavaScript and Node.js. Unfortunately nothing seems to be working for now. The first attempt was to use the cors-anywhere package which has been working so far. However the request returns an error saying something about browser addon. The second attempt was with cheerio following this tutorial `https://hackernoon.com/a-guide-to-web-scraping-with-javascript-and-nodejs-i21l3te1` but then there is the problem with CORS. Much to my surprise when trying GET request with postman with removed user agent the request returns the page. But if I set the user agent manually in the header in node.js I get the same error as before. My guess it that there is some server side restriction and the cors-anywhere is probably triggering it but I have no idea why the postman request is working and the node.js is not and how to tackle this problem.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
const getCurrencyStr = (el) =>
  (el.childNodes[0].nextElementSibling.innerHTML || "").trim();
const CURRENCIES = ["EUR", "USD", "GBP"];
const DEFAULT_CURRENCY = {
  USD: {
    buy: 1.0,
    sell: 1.0,
  },
  EUR: {
    buy: 1.0,
    sell: 1.0,
  },
  GBP: {
    buy: 1.0,
    sell: 1.0,
  },
};
const FIBankRate = () => {
  const [CurrencyRates, setCurrencyRates] = useState({
    USD: {
      buy: 1.5812,
      sell: 1.6461,
    },
    EUR: {
      buy: 1.94,
      sell: 1.96,
    },
    GBP: {
      buy: 2.078,
      sell: 2.186,
    },
  });
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(`https://www.fibank.bg/en/currency-rates`, {
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0",
      },
    })
      .then((response) => response.text())
      .then((result) => {
        if (result) {
          console.log(result);
          const el = document.createElement("html");
          el.innerHTML = result;
          const arr = Array.from(el.getElementsByTagName("tr"));
          console.log(arr);
          const filtered = arr.filter((el) => {
            return CURRENCIES.includes(getCurrencyStr(el));
          });
          filtered.forEach((el) => {
            const currentCurrency = getCurrencyStr(el);
            if (currentCurrency && currentCurrency in DEFAULT_CURRENCY) {
              DEFAULT_CURRENCY[currentCurrency].buy =
                el.childNodes[5].childNodes[1].childNodes[3].innerHTML;
              DEFAULT_CURRENCY[currentCurrency].sell =
                el.childNodes[5].childNodes[3].childNodes[3].innerHTML;
            }
          });
          setCurrencyRates(DEFAULT_CURRENCY);
        } else {
          throw new Error(result.message);
        }
      })
      .catch((error) => console.log(error.message));
  }, []);

  return (
    <tr>
      <td>FIBank</td>
      <td>{CurrencyRates.USD.buy}</td>
      <td>{CurrencyRates.USD.sell}</td>
      <td>{CurrencyRates.EUR.buy}</td>
      <td>{CurrencyRates.EUR.sell}</td>
      <td>{CurrencyRates.GBP.buy}</td>
      <td>{CurrencyRates.GBP.sell}</td>
    </tr>
  );
};
export default FIBankRate;
```

Comment: postman is not an internet browser and it doesn't use js engine designed to run in a browser, so you're not gonna get cors in postman

Comment: How is your React code is related to Node,js?

Comment: @Anatoly I don't understand your question.

Comment: Did you try to request this url only from a browser or from backend (NodeJs)?

Comment: @DanielManta I am aware of that. The question is can I somehow reproduce the postman request in node so I can get the much needed page in the response or simulate a browser like request?

Comment: @Anatoly browser works perfectly fine. You can try it. Node is giving me CORS error, so that's why I have used cors-anywhere. Unfortunately when using cors-anywhere I receive 400 error "The reason for this error could be add-on or extension in your browser".